# How do I display .mdb info in a label using an incrementing variable

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, ms-access

I am trying to set up an asp:label that displays one value from an ms-access database everyday.

I set up a variable "ID" that increments once a day and I am attempting to call the "Name" value from the .mdb using the "ID" variable as the row# which is "sID"
There are only three names on the database and the name should change everyday except on saturday and sunday.

When I run the site in the browser, there an no syntax errors.
But it displays nothing.

I'm not sure if my query or display code is wrong.

I have pasted my .vb code below.
on the .aspx all I have is

```
    Public Class Mat
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Public Sub page_load()

        Dim ID As Long
        Dim sConString As String
        Dim sCon As SqlConnection
        Dim scmd As SqlCommand

        sCon = New SqlConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Data\sAuditor.mdb")
        scmd = New SqlCommand()

        ID = 1
        If DatePart("hh", Now()) = 12 And DatePart("mi", Now()) = 0 And DatePart("ss", Now()) = 0 Then

            If DatePart("w", Now()) <> 0 And DatePart("w", Now()) <> 1 Then

                If ID < 3 Then
                    ID = ID + 1
                Else
                    ID = 1
                End If

            End If

        End If

        scmd.CommandText = "SELECT Name FROM EssAudit WHERE sID=ID"
        scmd.Connection = sCon

        Try

            sCon.Open()
            Dim sReader As SqlDataReader
            sReader = scmd.ExecuteReader

            While sReader.Read
                slabel.Text = sReader.Item("Name")
            End While

            sReader.Close()

        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try

        sCon.Close()

    End Sub


End Class
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question, the DatePart function is a holdover from VB6 days.  Your code would be easier to read using new methods: Now().Month, Now().Hour, etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not passing the value of ID, you are passing the string "ID" to the select statement.  Try this:

```
    scmd.CommandText = "SELECT [Name] FROM EssAudit WHERE sID=@ID"
    scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", ID)
```

I'll add that if you do something in you catch section, the error message might have helped you find the error.  Simply ignoring the error is rarely the way to go.